# Button disables on click but remains disabled when returning to same page via back button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

In our ASP.NET MVC application I have been assigned a task to disable button which links to another page (due to user clicking multiple times). The issue I am facing is the button remains disabled when the user comes back to the same page via browser back button.
Any help would be appreciated:

```
JSfiddle here:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/spdLnm2r/

I have purposley not add css classes as the issue is irrelevant to design.

Testet on Chrome Version 98.0.4758.82

Comment: What is the purpose of this?: onclick="window.location = 'spdLnm2r'

Comment: As far as i can test it, the button isn't disabled when i return to the page via browser back button